# UTL_SMTP utility in Adaptive Server Enterprise database

Tags: smtp

What is the counterpart of Oracle's utl_smtp utility in Adaptive Server Enterprise database.

Thank you

Comment: perhaps https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/17/configuring-sap-smtp-service/
Is there any functionality within UTL_SMTP that you're looking for?